# iPhone: UIButton don't use default pressed highlight

Tags: iphone, uibutton

Currently when you use a UIButton and press down on it, it gives the button a dark overlay as an indicator that the button was pressed.  I don't want this as I am implementing my own pressed state.

How can I remove this default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set it by setting the image for the control state. Think its

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected_day.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 22):

You could also set the appropriate property:

```
button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```